# Form Sending Null Query String to Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP that has a form that looks like this:

```
<form method="GET" action="ManagerLogicServlet?action=salesreport" >
                <select name="monthList">
                    <option value="1">January</option>
                    <option value="2">February</option>
                    <option value="3">March</option>
                    <option value="4">April</option>
                    <option value="5">May</option>
                    <option value="6">June</option>
                    <option value="7">July</option>
                    <option value="8">August</option>
                    <option value="9">September</option>
                    <option value="10">October</option>
                    <option value="11">November</option>
                    <option value="12">December</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

I am trying to send over a query string with attribute action = salesreport which will be a condition that will return a sales report for the selected month (don't mind the missing default value). I submit the form over to the ManagerLogicServlet which has this code snippet:

```
..String action = request.getParameter("action");

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("salesreport")){

        forward = SALES_REPORT;
        int month = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("monthList"));
        String monthString = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month-1];
        request.setAttribute("monthString", monthString);
        request.setAttribute("salesReport", salesDAO.getSalesReport(month));

    } else if..
```

But the action attribute is set to null. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

Because your form is using the `GET` method, the parameters from the `action` attribute are being discarded.  If you insist on using `GET`, then you can include an `<input>` tag containing the parameter you wish to pass on to the servlet.  Try doing this:

```
<form method="GET" action="ManagerLogicServlet?action=salesreport" >
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="salesreport">
    <select name="monthList">
        <option value="1">January</option>
        ...
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The alternative would be for you to leave your code as is, but change the form's method to `POST`.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. Do you know a better way that I could go about doing this in the future?

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to use a POST method here instead of GET?

Comment: @user5553362 Yes it would, that depends on whether you can change the server code to accept a `POST`  request instead of a `GET` request.

Comment: He is using J2EE so it should not matter whether the request comes in as a `GET` or a `POST` on the _server_ side.

Comment: Hmm then my understanding of when to use either is not correct. How come it's more appropriate for a POST here?

Comment: @user5553362 Because is more convenient to add the parameters (the ones that shouldn't be changed) in the `action` attribute instead of creating hidden HTML elements.

Comment: But when I use anchor tags with GET I am able to send over query strings such as this with attributes set properly. Why is this different?

Comment: @user5553362 I'm not sure, that is probably because when using a `form` with the `method` set to `GET` the url has to be generated using the `name`s and `value`s of the `form`'s elements.

Comment: Don't use an input of type text, hidden with CSS, for a hidden field. Use `<input type="hidden"`

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine.
I tried this

**HTML**

```
    <form action="AnyServlet?action=salesreport" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Data" />
    </form>
```

AnyServlet.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        System.out.println("action=="+action);


        }
```

Output

```
action==salesreport
```

**UPDATE**

When i changed from "post" to "get",I am getting issue too.You can use hidden input field if you want go with "get".

Comment: Didn't you change the form's method from `GET` to `POST`?

Comment: That is because you've set the method to `POST`